# Indirect objects in relative clauses - where to put the preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I've found this example for `point` [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/point):

> Carol looked to see what her finger was pointing at.

Can we rephrase the sentence as shown below?

> Carol looked to see **at what** her finger was pointing.

Why or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence:

- Carol looked to see at what her finger was pointing.

is terrible in English.

The verb "see" is a transitive verb, and needs a direct (not indirect) object.

- Carol looked to see **something**.

That something ("what" in the sentence) is at the same time the object to the preposition "at" in this other sentence:

- Her finger was pointing at **something**.

The only way both sentences can be linked together is by saying:

- Carol looked to see what her finger was pointing at.

This is because the verb "see" cannot be followed by a prepositional phrase.